# how to block sensitive words, but exempt if sensitive words follow with particular words

Tags: text, dfa

I am using DFA(deterministic finite automaton) for blocking sensitive words in a paragraph, but I meet with a problem is that:

for example, I want to block "I love", but if I love along with you can be exempt, that is "I love you". so If a paragraph contain "I love diamond", then it will be * * diamond, But if it's "I love you" there will not have blocking.

any suggestion will be helpful, thank you!

Comment: This isn't a good place to apply DFAs. A pure DFA deliverers only a 1-bit answer after consuming a string. A simple extension allows unique enumerated answer per state. A Mealy or Moore machine delivers a bit or enumerated value of output for each bit of input at the same time it's consumed. You're effectively asking for look-ahead: the bits for "I" and "love" depend on what comes next. That's not a DFA. Perhaps the best you can do is "look back." Recognize phrases and - upon finding one - allow complex-enough rules for labeling everything seen so far. I can't see this working very well.

Comment: This question probably is more fitting for: [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)